# Pushing data across App Engine instances

Tags: google-app-engine

Let's say we have several clients connected to App Engine using Channel API. Each client sends messages, which should be propagated to other conntected clients according to some rules. The tricky part is that clients may not be to the same App Engine instance.

Is there any way to *push* data from one instance to the others?

(Yes, I know about Memcache, but this would require some kind of polling.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking two questions here.

a. Can you push data from one instance to another without the use of polling.  The answer is generally no.

b. Can one client send messages to the server that can be propagated to other clients?  Yes, and this does not require propagating messages to other server-side instances.

Consider the Channel API as a service.  Clients are connected to the Channel API service; they are not connected to any particular instance.  Therefore any instance can send messages to any client.

1. You'll need to store the Channel tokens of your clients in the datastore, in some way that's queryable to match your rules.
2. Your client makes an HTTP request to send a message to your server.
3. The handler on the server queries for channel tokens that it needs to propagate the message to (either from memcache or datastore).
4. The handler on the server sends messages to all the clients.

If the list of destination clients is extremely large, you might want to do steps 3/4 in a task queue where the operation can run longer.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is the only one considering the broadcast behavior (plus I underestimated the Channel API). Do you have experience doing this in real live? You raised that there may be performance issues which leads to the question of how many clients can be delivered with a latency of a few seconds at maximum? Do you know if ChannelService.sendMessage runs synchronously?

Comment: The message is sent asynchronously.  However, AFAIK there's no batching, and GAE RPC calls all take some finite amount of time, so you'll need to loop and call sendMessage multiple times.  If you have huge numbers to send to, you might want to do it offline.  I'd do some real perf tests to see if it's actually necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what instance a client is connected to, that's hidden from you by the API.

Clients can only "reply" to message via standard HTTP commands, they don't actually have any way to respond via the channel API directly.

So Client A on server A1 wants to sent a message to client B on server B1.

Client A posts to a handler. That might be instance A1 or B1. It does not matter which as the server now passes the message on to client B whatever server client B is connected to via the Channel API.

The real point is that no App Engine instance has any data at all, in general. So it does not matter which instance you connect to, it might be the 99th instance or the very first to start up. So you have to design your application so that it's irrelevant what instance is in use.

1. Client sends message to server via HTTP.
2. Server sends message to N clients via the channel API.

Answer (score 0):

Channel API does not make a fixed frontend-instance-to-client connection. Any frontend instance can push message to channel if it knows the channel ID.

What you need to do is pass messages cross-channel.

1. User one sends message normally to server (e.g. via GET)
2. Server looks up channel ID of second user and pushes the message
3. Repeat procedure in other direction: second user to first user.